# Marklogic search grammar issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I was under the impression that when a search phrase is in double quotes, it will do the exact search. But I am getting partial matches as well (even though the score was low). I was expecting that it should do exact match. Following is my sample code.. am I missing something

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"  at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xqy";

let $q := '(“protein degradation”) AND ((context:PCS)) AND (sort:date_desc)'

let $options := 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <additional-query>
        <cts:collection-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
            <cts:uri>http://XXXXX/type/envelope</cts:uri>
        </cts:collection-query>
    </additional-query>
    <operator name="sort">
        <state name="date_desc">
            <sort-order type="xs:dateTime" direction="descending">
                <field name="upload_date"/>
            </sort-order>
        </state>
        <state name="date_asc">
            <sort-order type="xs:dateTime" direction="ascending">
                <field name="upload_date"/>
            </sort-order>
        </state>
    </operator>
    <constraint name="context">
        <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
            <element name="context" ns="http://XXXXX/metadata"/>
            <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
            <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
        </range>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="type">
        <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
            <element name="type" ns="http://XXXXX/metadata"/>
            <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
            <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
        </range>
    </constraint>
    <term>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
     <search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
</options>

let $start := 1
let $page-length :=1

let $result := search:search($q, $options, $start, $page-length) 
return $result
```

Following is what I got.. I am very confused.. I am not why the following result came as a hit

```
<search:result index="1" uri="/documents/PCS/0ba1e4a0190b77a3962e1218c3c1a7f4cb233ddf.xml" path="fn:doc("/documents/PCS/0ba1e4a0190b77a3962e1218c3c1a7f4cb233ddf.xml")" score="58624" confidence="0.329381" fitness="0.5856407">
  <search:snippet>
    <search:match path="fn:doc("/documents/PCS/0ba1e4a0190b77a3962e1218c3c1a7f4cb233ddf.xml")/*:document-envelope/*:metadata/*:context">
      <search:highlight>PCS</search:highlight>
    </search:match>
    <search:match path="fn:doc("/documents/PCS/0ba1e4a0190b77a3962e1218c3c1a7f4cb233ddf.xml")/*:document-envelope/*:extractedText/*:html/*:body/*:p[1]">
Analysis of the Safety Risks Associated with Hydrazine as a <search:highlight>Degradation</search:highlight> Product in LCIG RD12714 ra-rd12714-hydrazine</search:match>
    <search:match path="fn:doc("/documents/PCS/0ba1e4a0190b77a3962e1218c3c1a7f4cb233ddf.xml")/*:document-envelope/*:extractedText/*:html/*:body/*:p[9]">...of the Safety Risks Associated with Hydrazine as a <search:highlight>Degradation</search:highlight> Product in...</search:match>
  </search:snippet>
</search:result>
```

If we notice in the result above it match `<search:highlight>Degradation</search:highlight>` ... Why does it doing partial matches when we are trying to do exact search ?

----- Added the search:parse output ------

```
<cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">“protein</cts:text>
    <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>punctuation-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>whitespace-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>wildcarded</cts:option>
  </cts:word-query>
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">degradation”</cts:text>
    <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>punctuation-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>whitespace-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>wildcarded</cts:option>
  </cts:word-query>
  <cts:element-range-query operator="=">
    <cts:element xmlns:_1="http://XXXXX/metadata">_1:context</cts:element>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">PCS</cts:value>
    <cts:option>collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/</cts:option>
  </cts:element-range-query>
  <cts:annotation operator-ref="sort" state-ref="date_desc">
  </cts:annotation>
</cts:and-query>
```

Comment: Please share the output of search:parse with your query and options.  That's an excellent way to debug string search.

Comment: Added the search:parse output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the fancy quotes:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:parse('"protein degradation"')
```

gives:

```
<cts:word-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:text xml:lang="en">protein degradation</cts:text>
</cts:word-query>
```

while:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:parse('“protein degradation”')
```

gives:

```
<cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">“protein</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">degradation”</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
</cts:and-query>
```

Comment: Thank you.. Should have checked the parse function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the term-option called "exact"

From the docs:
"exact"
An exact match query. Shorthand for "case-sensitive", "diacritic-sensitive", "punctuation-sensitive", "whitespace-sensitive", "unstemmed", and "unwildcarded".

Comment: hmm... so what your suggesting is if there are quotes then I add the `<term-option>exact</term-option` and leave as is if no quotes ?

Comment: I'm thinking the term-option would apply to the entire search string, not just the phrase, correct?  So that would only work out for scenarios where the double quotes surround the entire search string . . .

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought as well... if only part of the search string has quotes then what will happen ?

Comment: Yes, to the entire search string. In the past, we have had to do quite some muscle work of using cts:tokenize on search strings and process things into more complex cts:searches. You might find benefit in digging deeper into search:parse as well